# How to remove chunks of text *with different length* from different texts in a character vector?

Tags: r, regex

I have a character vector that has 231 documents (231 rows by one column). The beginning of each document has a chunk of text that I would like to remove from each of 231 documents. The problem is that *the lenght of this chunk* varies from document to document.

Let's take an example where each text has the following beginning: Text that I wish to remove.:

I tried the following options without results:

```
x <- c("Text that I wish to remove because I don't like it. I really want to remove the text but I cannot do it. I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out.", 
  "Text that I wish to remove. I really want to remove the text but I cannot do it. I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out.", 
  "Text that I wish to remove and I will remove it because some great data analyst will help me solve it. I really want to remove the text but I cannot do it. I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out.", 
  "Text that I wish to remove and who know whether I manage to make it work, it could be and it could not be. I really want to remove the text but I cannot do it. I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out.")
```

If the chunk to be removed were equal I would simply do the following as someone suggested to me in a previous post:

```
strings <- substring(x, 60)
```

Yet, I am now stuck since the lenght differs for any text.

Ideally, I would like to get:

```
[1] "I really want to remove the text but I cannot do it. I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out."
[2] "I really want to remove the text but I cannot do it. I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out."
[3] "I really want to remove the text but I cannot do it. I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out."
[4] "I really want to remove the text but I cannot do it. I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out."
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How are you supposed to identify the text that should be removed? You need to define some rule that a computer can understand. Is it everything up to and including the first period?

Comment: The only logic I can see at the moment is "keep last 2 sentences", is this correct?

Comment: @zx8754 yes it is correct. The question that **MrFlick** asks is precisely what I need. How can I translate into a code "keep just the last two sentences"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following code

```
  gsub("^.+\\. ", "", x)

[1] "I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out."
[2] "I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out."
[3] "I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out."
[4] "I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out."
```

Comment: yes I tested it. The code I wrote before the modification also works.  it was `gsub(".+\\. ", "", x)` but was not safety.

Comment: @Arma_91 Glad it worked, just doesn't match with your expected output.

Comment: @zx8754 True. Yet, I got the reasoning behind now so I can adjust it to the text I have :)

Comment: @Arma_91 not to confuse future readers, I suggest you edit your expected output in the question.

Comment: Thanks @zx8754. I've just noticed that my output is different from the expected output. To obtain the expected output provided by @Arma_91, a right code should be `gsub("^.+?\\. ", "", x)` o `stringi::stri_replace_first(x, "", regex = ".+?\\. ")`.

Answer (score 1):

Split on `" ,"`, then get the last sentence:

```
sapply(strsplit(x, ". ", fixed = TRUE), tail, n = 1)
# [1] "I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out."
# [2] "I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out."
# [3] "I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out."
# [4] "I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out."
```